# apps under proxy not working in emulator though internet is working

Tags: android, android-emulator

I enabled proxy settings in 2.2 and 2.3 version of android in emulator and the internet started working but I have an application installed (which works only with proxy) is still not working. When I did the same for 4.0 version emulator, it was working there. Can anyone tell, why is it not working on 2.2 and 2.3 version though the internet is working.

Comment: Do you mean "I have an application installed **which** works only **when** proxy is not working"? The wording is important here to understand what is the problem. Also: what do you mean by app *not working on 2.2 and 2.3*? Does it crash on startup? Does it crash later on, when user does some specific action? Or maybe some feature is not working as expected?

Comment: I edited the question. By app not working, I mean that I couldn't log in but with same proxy settings in 4.0 emulator, I was able to log in.

Comment: What shows up in logs (logcat)? That you get a timeout or some other kind of error in communication occurs?

Comment: Yes, I get connection time out

Comment: Where are you setting up the proxy configuration? In the application or in the Emulator?

Comment: Look at my answer below. If you want you app to connect to the internet, what you've done is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring your proxy in the emulator allows the Browser application to use it, but any other applications need to be HTTP Proxy capable to access the internet.

Assuming you use the DefaultHttpClient class to connect to the internet, you'll have to add the following code to your android application before making the connection:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("yourproxy.domain.com", 3128); 
// Enter your proxy domain and port
client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

If you are using an authenticated proxy, you'll need to also have these lines:

```
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("yourproxy.domain.com", 3128),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("proxyusername", "password"));
```

Since you want the same code to work on both the emulator as well as a real phone, you should add a setting to the app which allows the user to turn on or off use of the proxy, and enter the proxy server/port/credentials instead of hard-coding them in the application.

Answer (score 6):

I also set up a proxy for the emulator in the Eclipse environment. It properly added the proxy address to the emulator startup command.

Yet I still struggled with it working only in some apps (like the browser) and not in others (like Maps) until I went into the WiFi settings *in the emulator* and entered the proxy address.

Note you **can't** use `http://` before the DNS name in this setting as you can in the emulator startup line.  (That took an hour to figure out.)

Answer (score 4):

You should try this (for Android 2.3):

```
1. > adb shell
2. # sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
3. sqlite> INSERT INTO system VALUES(99,’http_proxy', 'proxy:port');
4. sqlite>.exit
```

Also, you could try to define proxy explicitly when launching emulator via argument **http-proxy**

```
emulator -avd yourAVD -http-proxy http://yourproxy:port
```

Comment: Looks like this is bug in Android 2.X [bug reported on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5508&q=emulator%20proxy&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)